# Magento 2 Storview switcher is gone?

Tags: magento2, store-view, store-switcher

In Magento 1.9, when we created `multiple storviews` and *enable* all of them, then in the top navigation part of the page on frontend, there will be a dropdown  to let customers to switch between different storeviews.

It looks like this feature is gone in Magento 2? or at least it's not showing in default Luma theme. Can we get this storeview switcher on the frontend?

I'm using Magento 2.3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's displayed in footer by default.

```
<container name="footer" as="footer" label="Page Footer" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="footer content">
    <block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher" template="Magento_Store::switch/stores.phtml"/>
</container>
```

you can move it by using

```
<move element="store_switcher" destination="destination"/>
```